# How to wrap dialog to its content?

Tags: android, dialog, android-relativelayout, android-wrap-content

I want to show a dialog with a message and some buttons at the bottom of the dialog.

I intent to add more controls to dialog so I use a custom view.

Here is the code:

My `hv_popup.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#ffff00">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hvBottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MTD/HV" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEDIT"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EDIT" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CLOSE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etHV"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/hvBottomBar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.hv_popup);

final TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etHV);
tv.setText("text");
dialog.show();
```

Result:

[image]

The problem:

- When `etHV` have a short text, dialog take full space of the screen, while I only want it wrap to content height.
- When `etHV` have a long text, it take all space available, it push the button out of screen

My expected result:

- the dialog align to bottom of the screen
- the dialog wrap to its content height
- the buttons must always be visible, even when I set long text to `etHV`.
- when `etHV` have long text, it only take the remain space of visible dialog, which become scrollable and user still see the buttons at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: u need to change your layout..what do u want in dialog? textveiw and 3 button correct?

Comment: im not sure what is causing problems, but: https://github.com/WithoutCaps/DialogsCheatSheet check it out, may help. (there are quite a few dialog samples)       (for you "custom dialog" or "fragment dialog" should get the job done, i guess "fragment dialog" would be better in your case)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the layout to wrap the content. Try the following layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffff00">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etHV"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hvBottomBar"
        android:layout_below="@id/etHV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MTD/HV" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEDIT"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EDIT" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CLOSE" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Problem with your layout is when i set a long text to `etHV`, the buttons being hidden completely. I want those button always show when I set text to the textView

Comment: I am not getting any problem in setting big text

Comment: Have you tried with very long text? (> 300 lines). Yes still I can scroll up down to read full text, but the button being push away of the screen.